# ng-options and select library conflict

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

In my project I want use ng options instead of common

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

But my front-end developer is using some library for smooth selects and when I'm using ng-options with it params I'm getting a conflict angular and this library, mixed angular and jquery error, because this library uses jquery. How can I set into my model value of selected item?

Comment: is that `chosen` jquery plugin ?

Comment: nope
this one
http://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index3.html

Comment: Can you post the code that you're having a hard time with?